# Elevation around Compose Material 3 TopBar without using slot of Scaffold

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-elevation

If I add `TopBar` to the `Scaffold` in app top level composable then it looks as needed (shadow/elevation) when card items behind the bar:

[image]

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        Surface(shadowElevation = 3.dp) {
            TopAppBar(title = { Text("Test Title") })
        }
    }
) { padding ->
    // there's also should be NavHost but simplified for a sample code
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(padding),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
        items((0..25).toList()) {
            Card(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                    text = "Test card item ${it + 1}"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I don't want to add `TopBar` to `Scaffold` and allow each screen of the app to implement it itself then it doesn't look the same when cards behind the bar as it was in the first case, there are less shadows or they can disappear at all if color of topbar and card is the same which won't happen when using slot of `Scaffold`:

[image]

```
Scaffold { padding ->
    // there's also should be NavHost but simplified for a sample code
    Column {
        Surface(shadowElevation = 3.dp) {
            TopAppBar(title = { Text("Test Title") })
        }
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(padding),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
        ) {
            items((0..25).toList()) {
                Card(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                        text = "Test card item ${it + 1}"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the same effect but without using slot of `Scaffold`?

It looks the same as the first one only when cards are not behind top bar (no scroll):

[image]

Comment: it's better to use the scaffold for every screen, that means every screen has it's own top app bar.

Comment: @Srimani789 but you have to use one bottom bar, so it should be placed in scaffold of app top level composable, also when you hide bottom bar for some screens the scroll in columns can jump or navigation animations between screens will look ugly, so it's better not to use scaffold for each screen separately but just add top bar without it to each screen in column, and also pass window insets and app top level scaffold's paddings to each screen so you could manually configure it for screens with or without bottom bar and avoid scrolling jump or animations issues